# Android Fragment doesn't show on Large Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created an application using Fragments to show List on the left and details on the right.

Following is my layout in layout-large Appointments.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <include
        android:id="@+id/cust_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
  <fragment 
    class="com.myapp.blue.Fragments.ListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/frg_list"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frg_detail"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the Appointments.xaml from layout Folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/cust_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
    <fragment
        class="com.myapp.blue.Fragments.ListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/frg_list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for my Activity

```
public class AppointmentActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {        
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Set Content
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Appointments);        
        Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.cust_toolbar);
        //Set Action bar
        SetActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

The application runs flawlessly on Mobiles but when I run this application with Tablets None of my fragments show. I followed the instructions on this [Xamarin walkthrough](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/fragments_walkthrough/part_1_-_walkthrough/) and have seen other stackoverflow posts where they say that the width should be 0px or dp. But I cannot get the list fragment to show up on my Tablet. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your large layout has a toolbar `<include>` in a horizontal `LinearLayout`. If that toolbar is the full width of the `LinearLayout`, the `<fragment>` and `<FrameLayout>` are being pushed out the side of the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: So then How can I put my toolbar on top of this, should I use a horizontal linear in a vertical linear layout?

Comment: Sure, that'd work. That's what I'd do, anyway, since the weights `LinearLayout` provides seems to be something you're relying on. You might be able to do the same thing with just a `PercentRelativeLayout`, but I'm not sure. I've not used that.

Comment: Oh my god, I cannot believe I missed such a primitive thing. Thanks @MikeM. If you write that in an answer I will totally mark it for you, if you want

Comment: Oh, it's cool. You can accept @Ishamael's answer, if you like. Thanks, though. Appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the toolbar you include most likely has `layout_width=match_parent`, and as such occupies the entire linear layout with horizontal orientation. If you want your toolbar to be at the top, just make your linear layout vertical, and insert another horizontal linear layout inside with your fragments:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <include
        android:id="@+id/cust_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
  <LinearLayout 
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1">

      <fragment 
        class="com.myapp.blue.Fragments.ListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/frg_list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frg_detail"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mention width property in `dp` like `200dp`